# LINQ to Entities Right Join VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq

I am trying to figure out how to do a right join in vb.net I have tried several different approaches but neither works.

```vb
Dim query = From I In db.scll_label Where I.scll_transactiondate >= fromDate And I.scll_transactiondate <= toDate
            Join p In db.pt_mstr.Where(Function(pt) pt.pt_domain = "mueller") On I.scll_part Equals p.pt_part
            Join c In db.sclws_cfg.Where(Function(wk) wk.sclws_domain = "mueller") On I.scll_wsid Equals c.sclws_id
            Select New ShiftAdjustedModel With
                    {.Label = I,
                    .TransactionDate = I.scll_transactiondate,
                    .PartLength = p.pt_length,
                    .PartNetWeight = p.pt_net_wt,
                    .PartDescription = p.pt_desc1,
                    .PartTolHigh = p.pt_tol_high,
                    .PartType = p.pt_part_type,
                    .PartUM = p.pt_um,
                    .ProjCode = c.sclws_proj_code,
                    .Site = c.sclws_site}
```

output sql

```sql
SELECT 
[Extent1].[scll_ticket] AS [scll_ticket], 
[Extent1].[scll_domain] AS [scll_domain], 
[Extent1].[scll_site] AS [scll_site], 
[Extent1].[scll_part] AS [scll_part], 
[Extent1].[scll_qty] AS [scll_qty], 
[Extent1].[scll_weight] AS [scll_weight], 
[Extent1].[scll_transactiondate] AS [scll_transactiondate], 
[Extent1].[scll_transactiontime] AS [scll_transactiontime], 
[Extent1].[scll_shift] AS [scll_shift], 
[Extent1].[scll_pcs_bundle] AS [scll_pcs_bundle], 
[Extent1].[scll_bundle_lift] AS [scll_bundle_lift], 
[Extent1].[scll_cust] AS [scll_cust], 
[Extent1].[scll_wsid] AS [scll_wsid], 
[Extent1].[scll_userid] AS [scll_userid], 
[Extent1].[scll_remarks] AS [scll_remarks], 
[Extent1].[scll_calc_weight] AS [scll_calc_weight], 
[Extent1].[scll_total_feet] AS [scll_total_feet], 
[Extent1].[scll_tolerance] AS [scll_tolerance], 
[Extent1].[scll_drawlite_factor] AS [scll_drawlite_factor], 
[Extent1].[scll_total_tare] AS [scll_total_tare], 
[Extent1].[scll_tare_detail] AS [scll_tare_detail], 
[Extent1].[scll_out_of_tolerance] AS [scll_out_of_tolerance], 
[Extent1].[scll_tolerance_low] AS [scll_tolerance_low], 
[Extent1].[scll_tolerance_high] AS [scll_tolerance_high], 
[Extent1].[scll_std_weight] AS [scll_std_weight], 
[Extent2].[pt_length] AS [pt_length], 
[Extent2].[pt_net_wt] AS [pt_net_wt], 
[Extent2].[pt_desc1] AS [pt_desc1], 
[Extent2].[pt_tol_high] AS [pt_tol_high], 
[Extent2].[pt_part_type] AS [pt_part_type], 
[Extent2].[pt_um] AS [pt_um], 
[Extent3].[sclws_proj_code] AS [sclws_proj_code], 
[Extent3].[sclws_site] AS [sclws_site]
FROM   [dbo].[scll_label] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[pt_mstr] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[scll_part] = [Extent2].[pt_part]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[sclws_cfg] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[scll_wsid] = [Extent3].[sclws_id]
WHERE ([Extent1].[scll_transactiondate] >= @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[scll_transactiondate] <= @p__linq__1) AND ('mueller' = [Extent2].[pt_domain]) AND ('mueller' = [Extent3].[sclws_domain])
```

if i use this query

```vb
Dim query = From I In db.scll_label Where I.scll_transactiondate >= fromDate And I.scll_transactiondate <= toDate
            Group Join p In db.pt_mstr.Where(Function(pt) pt.pt_domain = "mueller") On I.scll_part Equals p.pt_part Into parts = Group
            Group Join c In db.sclws_cfg.Where(Function(wk) wk.sclws_domain = "mueller") On I.scll_wsid Equals c.sclws_id Into workstations = Group
            From p In parts.DefaultIfEmpty From c In workstations.DefaultIfEmpty
                                            Select New ShiftAdjustedModel With
                                                    {.Label = I,
                                                    .TransactionDate = I.scll_transactiondate,
                                                    .PartLength = p.pt_length,
                                                    .PartNetWeight = p.pt_net_wt,
                                                    .PartDescription = p.pt_desc1,
                                                    .PartTolHigh = p.pt_tol_high,
                                                    .PartType = p.pt_part_type,
                                                    .PartUM = p.pt_um,
                                                    .ProjCode = c.sclws_proj_code,
                                                    .Site = c.sclws_site}
```

i get this output

```sql
SELECT 
[Extent1].[scll_ticket] AS [scll_ticket], 
[Extent1].[scll_domain] AS [scll_domain], 
[Extent1].[scll_site] AS [scll_site], 
[Extent1].[scll_part] AS [scll_part], 
[Extent1].[scll_qty] AS [scll_qty], 
[Extent1].[scll_weight] AS [scll_weight], 
[Extent1].[scll_transactiondate] AS [scll_transactiondate], 
[Extent1].[scll_transactiontime] AS [scll_transactiontime], 
[Extent1].[scll_shift] AS [scll_shift], 
[Extent1].[scll_pcs_bundle] AS [scll_pcs_bundle], 
[Extent1].[scll_bundle_lift] AS [scll_bundle_lift], 
[Extent1].[scll_cust] AS [scll_cust], 
[Extent1].[scll_wsid] AS [scll_wsid], 
[Extent1].[scll_userid] AS [scll_userid], 
[Extent1].[scll_remarks] AS [scll_remarks], 
[Extent1].[scll_calc_weight] AS [scll_calc_weight], 
[Extent1].[scll_total_feet] AS [scll_total_feet], 
[Extent1].[scll_tolerance] AS [scll_tolerance], 
[Extent1].[scll_drawlite_factor] AS [scll_drawlite_factor], 
[Extent1].[scll_total_tare] AS [scll_total_tare], 
[Extent1].[scll_tare_detail] AS [scll_tare_detail], 
[Extent1].[scll_out_of_tolerance] AS [scll_out_of_tolerance], 
[Extent1].[scll_tolerance_low] AS [scll_tolerance_low], 
[Extent1].[scll_tolerance_high] AS [scll_tolerance_high], 
[Extent1].[scll_std_weight] AS [scll_std_weight], 
[Extent2].[pt_length] AS [pt_length], 
[Extent2].[pt_net_wt] AS [pt_net_wt], 
[Extent2].[pt_desc1] AS [pt_desc1], 
[Extent2].[pt_tol_high] AS [pt_tol_high], 
[Extent2].[pt_part_type] AS [pt_part_type], 
[Extent2].[pt_um] AS [pt_um], 
[Extent3].[sclws_proj_code] AS [sclws_proj_code], 
[Extent3].[sclws_site] AS [sclws_site]
FROM   [dbo].[scll_label] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[pt_mstr] AS [Extent2] ON ('mueller' = [Extent2].[pt_domain]) AND      ([Extent1].[scll_part] = [Extent2].[pt_part])
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[sclws_cfg] AS [Extent3] ON ('mueller' = [Extent3].[sclws_domain]) AND ([Extent1].[scll_wsid] = [Extent3].[sclws_id])
WHERE ([Extent1].[scll_transactiondate] >= @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[scll_transactiondate] <= @p__linq__1)
```

I simply want a right outer join on the two tables it translated into a left outer join. Even if I start with the tables for the right join as a lot of posts have suggested I get weird sql using cross joins and unions instead of right join.

Comment: A right join is just a left join with the tables reversed in order.  Why do you need a right join specifically?

Comment: I am so glad that you explained that because I am just starting to use EF and wanted to ensure that my SQL was being generated the same way as the original SQL statement which included a RIGHT OUTER JOIN statement. I read an article stating to construct your query so that it will apply in a left join statement.

Comment: I needed to have a list of all parts and workstations regardless if a ticket was assigned or not.

Comment: When translating sql to linq, its better to check that you're getting the right *data* rather than the right *sql*.  Left join is what you need, and clearly you know how to write one, so make sure its returning the records you expect.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think checking the data would be more efficient than trying to get the exact SQL generated. I learned something today ha-ha